# Nativescript Vue: Why does position of code matter in a Dock Layout matter?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Why does this following code produce this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOFxP.jpg ?
However, if I move the `BottomNavigatorBar` component to top position before `CountryListComponent`, it produces the desired result that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/98nVI.jpg ?

```
<template>
  <Page actionBarHidden="true">
      <DockLayout height="100%">

         // first
         <CountryListComponent dock="top">

         // second
          <BottomNavigationBar dock="bottom" activeColor="pink"
                            inactiveColor="yellow"
                            backgroundColor="black"
                            verticalAlignment="bottom"
                            @tabSelected="this.changeTab"
                            row="1">
              <BottomNavigationTab title="Fiaarst" icon="icon-29.png" />
              <BottomNavigationTab title="Second" icon="icon-29.png" />
              <BottomNavigationTab title="Third" icon="icon-29.png" />
          </BottomNavigationBar>

      </DockLayout>
  </Page>
</template>
```

***CountryListComponent***

```
<template>
        <StackLayout backgroundColor="blue">
        </StackLayout>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the [DockLayout documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layouts/layout-containers#docklayout), by default `stretchLastChild` will be `true` which means `BottomNavigationBar` will take entire space if it's last child and vice versa.